# Unable to display the ImageView in FrameLayout (Android)

Tags: android, android-camera

I had made a simple camera app and was thinking about customizing the view. Currently, I've been stuck with a problem with the ImageView not being able to be displayed on the top of the framelayout. Is there something wrong with the xml code below ? Or should I set some parameter in the code ?  All I want to do is to display the Imageview above the framelayout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/camera_preview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        >

        <LinearLayout

            android:orientation="horizontal"

            android:layout_width="wrap_content"

            android:layout_height="match_parent"

            android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/button_capture"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/shot_dot_icn" />
            </LinearLayout>
    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Your code has a ImageView inside a FrameLayout not on the top of it.

Comment: You need to clarify what you are trying to achieve. Draw a sketch or something. You layout doesn't make sense. Almost all the layouts in your current XML is useless. And replace fill_parent with match_parent, fill is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this layout, I am not sure if I understand your requirement though.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/button_capture"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/shot_dot_icn" />
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/camera_preview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        >

        <LinearLayout

            android:orientation="horizontal"

            android:layout_width="wrap_content"

            android:layout_height="match_parent"

            android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical">
            </LinearLayout>
    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem with the script below. All I had to do was to set the bringToFront() to the ImageView to set the view on top of the Framelayout.

```
  ImageView captureButton = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.button_capture);
        captureButton.bringToFront();
```